# Suddenly No sound in Kodi, on Ubuntu 16.04.1LTS

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, kodi

Yesterday it still worked fine. But as of today my sound in Kodi 16.1 suddenly doesn't work anymore, and I see an icon now that tells me there is no sound output in the top right corner(
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7H4K.png)).

I have a dual monitor setup, but the second monitor (where I'm watching videos from) doesn't have it's own audio source. I listen trough the default audio output of my laptop, and usually use headphones. Neither of the audio sources work in kodi now, but they keep on working outside kodi though. I played around in the system settings of kodi but nothing that I tried worked. I restarted the machine a few times, but it didn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix/approach this problem?
I'm happy to tell additional information if needed.

Comment: Kodi is muted. Have you used some remote control app like Kore (Android) and muted it there? It happened to me once and I took a long time to figure it out.

Comment: I have nothing like that. At least not that I know of. Any idea how to unmute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's fairly easy. Just press the **F10** key and it should toggle mute/unmute. I found out about it too just recently.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I must've pressed on F10 in the dark, when I tried to find the F7/F8 key for switching to primary monitor.

Comment: umm I'm just too curious, who are you thanking? XD

Comment: Ohh just to myself. It's fun to see someone spotted this in so much time xD